# ¿Como insertar imagen en 3 Capas?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Quisiera que me ayuden. Estoy realizando una inserción de imagen con SQL Server y C#. Estos son los campos de mi tabla:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[alumno] (
    [Alu_IMAGEN] [VARCHAR](250) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Este es mi Procedimiento almacenado llamado `Registrar_Alumno`

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Registrar_Alumno]
    @aluimagen VARCHAR(200)
    @opc int
AS
BEGIN
    IF @opc = 1
    begin
        INSERT INTO
            dbo.alumno (alu_Imagen)
        VALUES
            (@aluimagen)
        SELECT '1'
    end
END
```

Como les Comentaba he realizado en 3 capas soy nuevo en esta metodología y quisiera que me ayuden ya que no me logra insertar una imagen a mi BD.

Estoy usando un open.file dialog pero cuando selecciono una imagen en mi campo no se registra la ubicación de la imagen y creo que eso es el problema.

Les agradesco

Esta es la capa Dato:

```cs
public class Cls_D_Alumno
{
    private static string conexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CnxLogin"].ConnectionString;

    public static DataTable RegistrarAlumno(Cls_E_Alumno objE)
    {
        return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataTable(conexion, "Registrar_Alumno", objE.Imagen,objE.Opc);
    }
}
```

Esta es la capa Entidad:

```cs
public class Cls_E_Alumno
{
    private string imagen;

    public string imagen
    {
        get { return imagen; }
        set { imagen= value; }
    }

    private int opc;

    public int Opc
    {
        get { return opc; }
        set { opc = value; }
    }
}
```

Esta es la Capa Presentacion :

```cs
private void btnRegistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        objE.Imagen = txtImagen.Text;
        objE.Opc = 1;

        string resp = Cls_N_Alumno.RegistrarAlumno(objE).Rows[0][0].ToString();
        if(resp == "1")
        {
            Limpiar();
            MessageBox.Show("Registro Correctamente", "Aviso del Sistema");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al Registrar", "Aviso del Sistema");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Esta es la Imagen de mi Presentación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En ese botón de `...` es donde van a seleccionar la imagen, para ello estoy usando este método del open File.

```cs
private void btnImagen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if(this.openFileDialog1.FileName.Equals("") == false)
        {
            pictureBox1.Load(this.openFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No se Pudo Cargar la Imagen", "Aviso del Sistema");
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Pierro. No estoy seguro si es que la pregunta no es clara o si es que simplemente es demasiada amplia, pero necesitas ser mucho más específico en cuanto a cual es tu pregunta/problema, y si es que recibes algún mensaje de error. También, tal vez te sea util repasar como crear un [mcve].

Comment: Si tienes razon lo reducire lo mas minimo. modificare mi pregunta

Comment: @sstan ya lo modifique espero que esta vez sea bien mi pregunta

Comment: Excelente que lo hayas reducido. Ahora falta que esclarezcas esta parte: *quisira que me ayuden ya que no me logra insertar ni mostrar la imagen ya que anterior mente lo hice sin insertar una imagen y me funciono.*. ¿Hay algún error? ¿Cual error recibes?  Algo que te sugiero hacer de una vez es remover el `try-catch`. Tener un `catch` vacío no es buena práctica, y justamente causaría de tapar cualquier error que esté sucediendo.

Comment: @sstan Muchas gracias por tus consejos la verdad no sabia eso de Try ya que yo paro viendo videos de youtube y todos usaban y pensaba que era bien usar pero bueno. si ahora pongo las imagen mas detalladas para que si me puedes ayudar amigo

Comment: Espero que me Puedan ayudar. @sstan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bien puedo marcarte algunos puntos que creo podrian resolver el problema, lo primero que noto es que en ninguna parte del codigo estas asignando el path de la imagen seleccionada al `txtImagen`, cuando seleccionas la imagen con el `openFileDialog1` asignas esta al `pictureBox1`, pero luego veo que utilizas para definir la entidad:

```
objE.Imagen=txtImagen.Text;
```

pero falto asignarle el path de la imagen al textbox (o al menos no mostraste esa parte del código), es por eso que no llega nada a las otras capas.

Tampoco es recomendable si usas entidades que el metodo RegistrarAlumno() retorne un datatable, se que usas el SqlHelper, pero deberias abastraer la respuesta que este genera y retornar una entidad o un valor si.

Algo que es muy util serie que pongas un breakpoint en el codigo y vayas analizando paso a paso que valores tienen las variables de esta forma conocer si las estas asigando.

En el metodo del evento `btnRegistrar_Click`, quita el catch vacion, NUNCA se define un try..catch sino vas a realizar algo con este, como ser al menos loguear el problema en un archivo, porque despeus hay problemas y nunca te enteras que esta pasando. Si no vas a realizar nada con el error entonces no definas el try..catch

Analiza este artículo

[[WinForms] Edición Empleados](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2011/02/winforms-edicion-empleados-grabar.html)

alli explico como trabajar en capas usando entidades

Comment: Muchas gracias la  verdad soy nuevo y como vi un tutorial que usaban asi el uso de las 3 capas y entidades y try cactch yo por instucion pense que asi se trabajaba .
te agradesco un monton.

Ahora revisare y vere y aprendere a trabajar correctamente las capas

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,
Tu código está sujeto a muchas mejoras, pero enfocándonos en la pregunta tal cual la haces, el código del botón "btnImagen" tiene algunos errores, como por ejemplo desde ahí deberías llenar la propiedad txtImagen.Text, pues veo que desde ahí tomas la ruta de la imagen.
La corrección para ese código es la siguiente:

```
    private void btnImagen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                txtImagen.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                pictureBox1.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"No se pudo cargar la imagen.{Environment.NewLine}{ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Por ejemplo, el método ShowDialog regresa la respuesta del usuario. Si el usuario presiona Aceptar, se entiende que sí vas a realizar la operación, pero si cancela ya sea con la tecla ESC o presionando Cancelar, no se debería realizar la operación.
Lo siguiente creo que resuelve tu duda de golpe, es que se debe llenar la propiedad Text del control txtImagen, pues ese valor es el que estás tomando en el botón del Registro.
espero que este código te sirva para aclarar un poco tus dudas.